# Function not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, scope

so I have these two functions and then another function calling them.  It seems like I'm losing scope, between function calls.

```
var determineInteractionType = function( interaction ){

    var param = interaction.parameterSet.param;

    param.forEach(function( parameter, index, array ){
        if( parameter.name === "INTERACTION-TYPE" ){
            return parameter.value;
        }
    });
    return null;
};

var getInteraction = function( id ){        

    customInteractions.forEach( function(interaction, index, array){            
        if( interaction.id == id ){
            alert( id );
            return interaction;
        }
    });
    return null;
};
```

Here is the piece of code calling the functions.  The error is that even though getInteraction is returning a value it is showing up that determineInteraction is getting passed an argument of null.

```
var _convertStemFromEAS = function(stem) {
    var reg = new RegExp('@\{PRESENTATION-HTML-INTERACTION\}=&quot;(.*?)&quot;');
    var result;
    var count = 1;      

    while ((result = reg.exec(stem)) !== null) {

        var Match = result[0];
        var dropdownGuid = result[1];

//The Error seems to be right here
        var interactionType = determineInteractionType( getInteraction( id ) );


        if( interactionType === "shortTextInteraction" ){           
            var escaped = $('<div/>').text('<select id="' + NewTmpGuid() + '" data-choice-id="' + dropdownGuid + '" style="width:100px;" data-count="' + count + '" class="easSelection"><option>DD' + count + '</option></select>').html();
        }else if( interactionType === "essayTextInteraction" ){

        }

        count += 1;
        stem = stem.replace(Match, escaped);
    }   
    return stem;    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`determineInteraction` is returning null because that's what it's coded to return.

When you `return` from the inner function in the forEach loop, you're not returning from `determineInteraction`.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
var determineInteractionType = function( interaction ){

    var 
    returnValue = null,
    param = interaction.parameterSet.param;


    param.forEach(function( parameter, index, array ){
        if( parameter.name === "INTERACTION-TYPE" ){
            returnValue = parameter.value;
        }
    });

    return returnValue;
};
```

Comment: I had just figured out what I needed to do but not why.  I'd give you plus 5 for the why.  Common error pattern in javascript I feel like.

Comment: I don't think that `return false` is going to break the `forEach`.